# Intelligent number formatting in .net

Tags: .net, formatting

I'm in the process writing a 'clever' number formatting function, which would behave this way :

```
1500 -> 1.5k
1517 -> 1 517
1234000 -> 1 234k
1200000 -> 1.2M
```

Is it possible to do this using double.toString() or another .net built-in class ?

I know it's quite easy to code, but I'd rather reuse the framework classes if the functionality already exists.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is anything like that in .NET.  Here's the key part of a PowerShell script I have to do this for me.

```
$prefixes = @('', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E', 'Z', 'Y')
$base = 1024;

$magnitude = [Math]::Floor([Math]::Log($_, 1024))

Write-Verbose "`$magnitude = $magnitude"

if($magnitude -eq 0)
{
    [string]$mantissa = $_
    [string]$label = 'B';
}
else
{
    [string]$mantissa = [String]::Format("{0:N}", $_ / [Math]::Pow(1024, $magnitude))

    Write-Verbose "`$mantissa = $mantissa"

    [string]$label = $prefixes[$magnitude]

    if ($IEC)
    {
        $label += "i"
    }

    $label += $unit
}


[String]::Format("{0} {1}", $mantissa, $label)
```

It needs to be updated to use PowerShell V2's Advanced Functions.  (The parts that I didn't paste in are the parts that try to do what Advanced Functions do, and it's messy.)

Answer (score 0):

The .NET libraries do not have anything quite like what you're looking for, but using [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) you could add that functionality to them. Note that you can't override methods using extensions, only add new ones.

However, architecturally, I would be better to extend the classes you need using [polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx) and [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) the ToSting methods. This would avoid the overhead of extension methods, but still allow you to pass around your custom class to methods expecting a .NET number type.

Comment: Well, I think I'll rather just use an helper method whenever I need to format my numbers. In my case, it's not often enough to justify extending the double type...